# Ensure/Sync default content paths for environment AdventureWorksAuthoring failed during SXC installation

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework

In addition to my previous [question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11888/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-error-while-sitecore-experience-commerce), When I tried to re-execute the script with the help of script provided by [Alex](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/646/alex-smagin) in his [repository](https://github.com/asmagin/sitecore-installation-scripts) and my previous exception resolved but got one more error.

```
Commerce Services BootStrapping completed

[--------------------------- EnsureSyncDefaultContentPaths : EnsureSyncDefaultContentPaths ---------------------------]
Ensure/Sync default content paths for: AdventureWorksAuthoring
Checking if https://commerce-shops.sc9u1.sc/commerceops/CheckCommandStatus(taskId=1934) has completed ...
Ensure/Sync default content paths for environment AdventureWorksAuthoring failed, please check Engine service logs for more info.
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : ScriptHalted
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253
char:21
+                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
```

When I gone through the service logs (mentioned in above error log), I see below exception:

```
8 21:58:58 INFO Management.block.getitemsbypath./sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Commerce Engine Settings/Commerce Terms/BusinessTools/ViewPropertyNames|en
8 21:58:58 ERROR SitecoreConnectionManager.Error: Message=Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.|Trace=   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.SitecoreConnectionManager.ProcessRequest(CommerceContext commerceContext, String action, String method, ItemModel itemModel)
System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.SitecoreConnectionManager.ProcessRequest(CommerceContext commerceContext, String action, String method, ItemModel itemModel)
8 21:58:58 ERROR Management.block.getitemsbypath: Sitecore Item Service Get item failed, Item /sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Commerce Engine Settings/Commerce Terms/BusinessTools/ViewPropertyNames not found.
```

I checked `ViewPropertyNames` and other nodes in Sitecore tree and all are there. My doubt on hostname related issue but not sure, which hostname the script is looking for. I cross verified all applications hosted in IIS and entries are there in the host file.

Thus not sure, what exactly the hostname missing here?

Comment: Where to check "Engine Service Logs" for more details? I am also facing same issue

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari, Go to IIS Manager, Right click on shops role (In current case commerce-shops.sc9u1.sc) and Select Explore option from the context menu. Now from the File Explorer, navigate to wwwroot\logs folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the logs you posted, it seems the Script can't find a valid hostname required to continue the installation further. Please make sure:

1. The bindings with HTTPS (port 443) must be there in your IIS for your
   website.
2. Also the hostname of the Sitecore website must be in the
   `AllowedOrigins` Property of the `config.json` file.

Once done, try re-executing the steps again, you should be good.

Comment: in which config.json Files I have to look at?

Comment: It's Config.json, can be found under wwwroot on Authoring.

Comment: I did the fix as suggested here but it did not worked. My service logs say "ERROR CtxMsg.Error.ContentPathAlreadyExists: Text=Content path '/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel' already exists. " Any clue on what need to be done?

Comment: Same error happened for me. As per step 1, I went on to check the binding and found that relevant certificated was not linked with binding. Also the Authorization was failing. I corrected both and it start working.

Answer (score 0):

On IIS, my website was stopped due to other website running under the same port. stop the other site then start the site that you want to install XC. This was my issue.